# jQuery bootstrap dropdown on hover normally and on click for small devices Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap typical nav with dropdown.

I want the dropdown to show on hover and hide on mouseout. But when the device width is less than 979px I want the dropdown to show on click instead of hover.

I wrote some jQuery to achieve this. It works fine but when I decrease the browser width to less than 979px it shows the dropdown on hover. I want this to only show dropdown on click. Ironically, If I keep the browser width at less than 979px then it doesnt show on hover.

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 979) {
    $(".md-nav ul.nav li.dropdown").click(function () {
        $('li.dropdown > a').addClass('dropdown-toggle');
        $('li.dropdown > a').attr('data-toggle','dropdown');

    });
    }

    if ($(window).width() > 979) {
        $(".md-nav li.dropdown").hover(function () {
            $(".md-nav li.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu").stop(true,true).delay(400).show(0);
        }, function () {
            $(".md-nav li.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu").stop(true,true).delay(500).hide(0);
        }); 
    }

  });
```

My HTML for the navigation:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default md-nav" role="navigation">
     <div class="container-fluid">
        <select class="nav-sel">
            <option value="Vous Etes">Vous Etes</option>
            <option value="Vous Etes">Vous Etes</option>
            <option value="Vous Etes">Vous Etes</option>
            <option value="Vous Etes">Vous Etes</option>
        </select>

        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Ministére</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Promotion</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Prévention</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Les Féderations</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Le diréct</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Emplois & Mériers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Grand Evénements</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <img src="img/athlete-img1.jpg" alt="athlete running" />
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Sport</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Promotion</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Prévention</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Les Féderations</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Le diréct</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Emplois & Mériers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Grand Evénements</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <img src="img/athlete-img1.jpg" alt="athlete running" />
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Jeunesse</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Promotion</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Prévention</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Les Féderations</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Le diréct</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Emplois & Mériers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Grand Evénements</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <img src="img/athlete-img1.jpg" alt="athlete running" />
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Publications</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Promotion</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Prévention</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Les Féderations</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Le diréct</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Emplois & Mériers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Grand Evénements</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <img src="img/athlete-img1.jpg" alt="athlete running" />
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Mediatheque</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Promotion</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Prévention</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Les Féderations</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Le diréct</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Emplois & Mériers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Grand Evénements</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <img src="img/athlete-img1.jpg" alt="athlete running" />
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Espace Medias</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Comment: This approach is flawed. Screen size and hoverability aren't intrinsically related.

Comment: cant we write something like "it should always show dropdown on hover except when screen size is smaller than 979px then it should only show dropdown on click'?

Comment: Tablets with large screens exist.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because your current logic is the following:

1. check screen size (width)
2. create event handler for `click` if `width` is less than 979
3. create event handler for `hover` if `width` is greater than 979

Which, in short, means the width check is only performed once when you open the page, and the event handler is attached accordingly. To overcome this, I suggest using an alternative logic:

1. add event handler for `click` and for `hover`
2. on click if browser width is less than `979px` show dropdown
3. on hover if browser width is greater than (or equal) to `979px` show dropdown

**Javascript**

```
$(".md-nav ul.nav li.dropdown").click(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 979) {
        $('li.dropdown > a').addClass('dropdown-toggle');
        $('li.dropdown > a').attr('data-toggle','dropdown');            
    }
});

$(".md-nav li.dropdown").hover(function () {
    if ($(window).width() >= 979) {
        $(".md-nav li.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu").stop(true,true).delay(400).show(0);
    }
}, function () {
    if ($(window).width() >= 979) {
        $(".md-nav li.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu").stop(true,true).delay(500).hide(0);
    }
});
```

Another alternative would be following your logic and attaching the given event handler depending on browser width, and refreshing this each time the browser window is resized:

**Javascript**

```
$(window).on('resize', function (e) {
    // reattach event handler if necessary
});
```

Keep in mind, however, that with this approach you need to delete the previous event handlers, or they will stack on top of each other.

Comment: this approach has the issue that unless the browser size is resized, meaning by default, the dropdown wouldnt show on neither hover nor click. Is there a way to write something like "if screen size is less than 979px on hover do nothing"? which should overwrite the previous hover function. I think that would solve this problem

Comment: @AlexZahir That's strange, it _should_ appear. I couldn't do an in-depth test due to a lack of stylesheet, but it should work. _"if screen size is less than 979px on hover do nothing"_ - this snippet is (should be) exactly what you are asking, in addition to not showing dropdown with a click on larger screens (windows).